# Flooded with UDP bad checksum on port 53 (but port is closed and checksum offloaded)

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have a virtual server that I run a web server and openvpn on.

It is not running bind, and port 53 is closed.

I am recently getting *flooded* with errors in syslog (about 1/sec) such as:

```
Sep 29 15:06:59 kernel: [4579319.118505] UDP: bad checksum. From 128.47.17.191:4127 to <<my server IP>>:53 ulen 49
Sep 29 15:07:31 kernel: [4579350.981024] UDP: bad checksum. From 69.161.227.72:27788 to <<my server IP>>:53 ulen 39
```

I've tried checksum offloading with:

```
ethtool --offload eth0 rx off tx off
```

Finally I simply blocked all UDP traffic with iptables.  I had to remove a rule that was allowing all UDP traffic, which is a bit concerning.
    iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP

So that leaves two questions:

1. Why was I receiving these errors - was this an attack of some sort?
2. What UDP ports do I need to allow in my iptables to make sure my VPN
   and web server continue to function properly?  Do I need to allow
   UDP port 53 to my DNS servers?

Comment: port 53 UDP is DNS are you sure it's closed? `netstat -anu | grep 53` can't imagine why someone would want to knock on closed port unless they're DOSing?

Comment: `netstat -anu | grep 53` doesn't return anything, so presumably it's closed now.  It was open when I was getting the traffic.